# Add array to subdocument Mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am trying to add an array to an existing subdocument in Mongoose using Express, but I can't seem to figure it out

This is my Mongoose model:

```
var subitems = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: ObjectId,
  title: String,
  messages: Array
});

var menuItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  subitem: [subitems]
}, {collection: 'menu_items'});

module.exports = mongoose.model("menu_items", menuItems);
```

I am using the ID from the subdocument to update the specific item in "subitem"
This is the Express Update:

```
postController.postArticles = function(req, res,item) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var saveData = {
    title: req.body.title,
    text: req.body.text
  };
  item.update({_id: id}, {$push:{messages: saveData}},(err, result) => {
  });
};
```

It is not adding anything to the db, anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

With mongoose you have to update the whole object. So, first you get item with find or findOne, and the you have to add the element to the array with push, and finally you call .save() method of the mongoose object.
Something like this:

```
postController.postArticles = function(req, res,item) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  item.findOne({_id: id}, function(error, myItem) {
    var saveData = {
      title: req.body.title,
      text: req.body.text
    };
    myItem.messages.push(saveData);
    myItem.save();
  });
};
```

Comment: I forgot a parenthesis. In fact, as you are not using promises here, it needed a callback. Try it now

Comment: Not working either. Keeps telling me "cannot read property 'push' of null"

Comment: That's because it is not finding the object. make sure you are receiving the id well. Check if error has any value and print it. And the push has to be done to messages field, but that's not what the error is about.

Comment: The Id is received well, so I dont know what the problem is

Comment: Make sure the id exists in that collection in the db, and make sure you are passing items collection well ... Print error and myItem in order to know whats happening. Give some clues

Comment: The id exists in the collection and both myItem and error returns null

Comment: Try with find and see if document is found

Comment: If I do a "find" on the main document id, it finds them, but if I do a "find" on the subdocuments id, it does not find them